# how to monitor crond service in nagios

Tags: centos, nagios, nrpe

I want to monitor crond service in Nagios.

I tried using creating below script and put at `/usr/local/nagios/libexec/`

```
CRON_RESULT=$(/etc/init.d/crond status)
STATUS=`echo $CRON_RESULT| grep pid`
if [ -z "$STATUS" ]; then
        echo "CROND CRITICAL- $CRON_RESULT"
        exit 2
else
        echo "CROND OK- $CRON_RESULT"
        exit 0
fi
```

It is working fine if no cron is running (shows CRITICAL) & if running (shows OK).

But if NRPE client is not reachable from Nagios Server, crond service shows the status as "OK" (in green color) with a message `return code of 255 is out of bounds`. And I can't get to know that crond is running or not.

Is there any other way to monitor crond service in CentOS 6.6?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched and find that it is bug in nrpe v2.15 so I reverted back to nrpe v2.12 on Nagios Server and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From your `libexec` directory on your Nagios server, manually execute the `check_nrpe` command against the IP address of the host which contains the `crond` service you want to monitor:

```
[root@joeyoung.io libexec]# pwd
/usr/local/nagios/libexec
[root@joeyoung.io libexec]# ./check_nrpe -H 10.0.0.1
connect to address 10.0.0.1 port 5666: No route to host
```

Immediately after running `check_nrpe`, execute `echo $?` to get the return code.

```
[root@joeyoung.io libexec]# echo $?
255
```

If you get a result of `255`, (or any number other than 0), then the error message you received manually executing `check_nrpe` is a symptom of the root cause of your issues.

Can you try running this and reporting back?

Comment: Yes it was same 255 error code but is it mean i have to edit nrpe file?

I searched and find that it is bug in nrpe2.15 so reverting back to nrpe2.12 on Nagios Server resolved my problem.

Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Did your problem get solved when you downgraded to 2.12? If not, can you post the full output of the manual check_nrpe error message?